# Rails input for hours and minutes without locale and timezone

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have an entity with a attribute `duration`. In the database (which is Postgres) its type is `interval`.

In the web page view I want to put an input field for this attribute, but it seems none of the time helpers are useful for the purpose I want, because they are intended for 24hs formats.

In this field I want to be able to store something like `1000:00` which it would be 1000 hours or `00:30` which would be half hour.